# Google app engine and machine learning

Tags: google-app-engine, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence

I Can to run machine learning  on Google App Engine? I can utilized api intellige artificial in google app engine?

Answer (score 1):

Google cloud have Cloud ML Engine for the exact purpose. Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine is a managed service that enables you to easily build machine learning models that work on any type of data, of any size. Create your model with the powerful TensorFlow framework that powers many Google products.

With Google ML Engine you can do the following things

1. Predictive Analytics at Scale
2. Build Machine Learning Models Easily
3. Fully Managed Service
4. Deep Learning Capabilities

It also include lot of other features too 
Read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/)

Comment: ok i read, 
I created a webpApp with php and a chatbot with a telegram and communicated with each other so I wanted to know if putting my webapp on the app engine, then I could call the bees of machine learning, basically I have to provide artificial intelligence to my webapp